# How to make full screen background in a web page

Tags: html, css, web

How to make an image as background for web page, regardless of the screen size displaying this web page? I want to display it properly. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via jQuery plugins ;)

- http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/
- http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Answer (score 25):

its very simple
use this css (replace image.jpg with your background image)

```
body{height:100%;
   width:100%;
   background-image:url(image.jpg);/*your background image*/  
   background-repeat:no-repeat;/*we want to have one single image not a repeated one*/  
   background-size:cover;/*this sets the image to fullscreen covering the whole screen*/  
   /*css hack for ie*/     
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.image.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Answer (score 20):

um why not just set an image to the bottom layer and forgo all the annoyances

```
<img src='yourmom.png' style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1;'>
```

Comment: @str8: because stretching? just saying.

Comment: Perfect, Fixed my issue! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use this CSS to make full screen backgound in a web page.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:url("https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/106/719/original/vector-abstract-blue-wave-background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your CSS

```css
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[here's the link where i found it:](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a div 100% wide and 100% high. Then set a background image.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for keywords [background generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=background+generator) shows this **[CSS3 produced](http://bgpatterns.com/)** background pattern that's dynamically created.

By keeping the image **small and repeatable**, you won't have problems with it loading on mobile devices and the small **image file-size** takes care of memory concerns.

Here's the markup for the `head` section:

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
      background-image:url('path/to/your/image/background.png');
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

</style>
```

If your going to use an image of something that should preserve **aspect ratio**, such as people or objects, then **you don't want 100%** for width and height since that will stretch the image out of proportion. Instead check out this **[quick tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)** that shows different methods for applying background images using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS

```
.bbg { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('...');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;    
}
```

#### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="h-100">
.
.
.
<body class="bbg">
</body>
.
.
.
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Specifically, the first [Demo](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php) was the one that helped me out a lot!

```
CSS
 {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

this might help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why there is always a white boder of the background image, if I put the image in a 'div' element inside 'body'.
But the image can be full screen, if I put it as background image of 'body'.

Because the default 'margin' of 'body' is not zero.
After add this css, the background image can be full screen even I  put it in 'div'.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```