# How to make this background-image responsive

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I'm trying to make my "Icon_POS_bitmap.png" responsive. If I view the Website on a laptop, the image is cut off at the bottom. I know i can't put the `.hero-slides .single-hero-slides` on a fixed 1000px height. But `height: 100%; and height: auto;` doesn't seem to work.

When I try to set things on auto or 100%, the image disappears and the following div "`sonar-project-areas`" goes at the top.

**HTML**

```
<section class="hero-area">
  <div class="hero-slides">
    <!-- Single Hero Slide -->
    <div class="single-hero-slide bg-img slide-background-overlay" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/Icon_POS_bitmap.png);">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```css
.hero-slides .single-hero-slide {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 800ms;
    transition-duration: 800ms;
    overflow: visible;
    /*cursor: pointer; */
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(75%);
    transform: translateY(75%);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 800ms;
    transition-duration: 800ms;
    bottom: 0;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content .line {
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content p {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    margin-top: 140px;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide:hover .hero-slides-content {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide:hover p {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.bg-img {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide-background-overlay {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
}

.slide-background-overlay::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The original Template i use is this: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/sonar/

I modify it for my needs.
I use html/css/js from time to time but i can't find the issue.

Greetings Adrian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make full screen background in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869739/how-to-make-full-screen-background-in-a-web-page)

Comment: @Adam sadly not. My main problem is the disappearing image whenever i try the suggestet solutions..

Comment: Did i miss understood this? You want the image to be responsive and cover the full screen on web browser and mobile device?

Comment: @Adam Yes this is exactly what i want. But every common solution doesn't seem to work since the image disappears. When you follow the link to the original template, you can see how it looks. I just replaced the caroussel at the top with a single image.

Comment: Okay! Check my answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're trying to do, I added `height: 100vh` to the main container and moved the `style="background: ...."` inside the css in `.bg-img` . I also added `margin: 0; padding: 0` to the body

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  paddong: 0;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide {
  height: 100vh;
  /* You can change this to 50vh (50% of the screen width) and will still be responsive */
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 800ms;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
  overflow: visible;
  /*cursor: pointer; */
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(75%);
  transform: translateY(75%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 800ms;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content .line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide .hero-slides-content p {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  margin-top: 140px;
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide:hover .hero-slides-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.hero-slides .single-hero-slide:hover p {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.bg-img {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/5472/3648?image=1074");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide-background-overlay {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}

.slide-background-overlay::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero-area">
  <div class="hero-slides">
    <!-- Single Hero Slide -->
    <div class="single-hero-slide bg-img slide-background-overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This actually works perfect! Thanks, i really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to create a responsive background image. If that's the case, you'll find below a quick hint on how to do it.

---

## Responsive image background:

1. We first create a container for the background like you did with `<div class="single-hero-slide bg-img slide-background-overlay"></div>`
2. Next, you set an height and/or a width with `width` and `height` CSS properties
3. After that, select an image to use as background and use `background-size: cover` *or* `contain`

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1034677/pexels-photo-1034677.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=adult-art-man-1034677.jpg&fm=jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-hero-slide bg-img slide-background-overlay"></div>
```

Here is a reference of this property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, same issue. The image disappears and the div below slides to the top. Strange thing: when i open the development-tools in the browser, it magically appears. As soon as i close the development-tools, it disappears again