# How do I make my website background fill the screen in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have made two forms on my website, both being surrounded by one `<div class="wrapper">` tag. I used CSS to add a background image to this.

```
.wrapper {
    background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/desktop.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 950px;
}
```

However, this is what the site actually looks like. I can't extend the bottom of the image to fill the screen. I can't figure out why it's doing this.

[image: Screenshot of what it looks like]

Comment: This is not PHP relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make full screen background in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869739/how-to-make-full-screen-background-in-a-web-page)

Answer (score 2):

The height of div is 100% of what? If it is a direct child of body, the body is not wrapping 100%  of the screen by default. So you have to make body 100% and then the wrapper will also take 100% of body. If there are more parent elements, all of them also should have style `height:100%` :

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Also add `background-size:cover` to make sure that the image stretch enough to cover the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-size:cover` to have the background cover the entire div. Your background will only show behind the content contained within it. You need to change the height or padding of your container and/or add more content to see the whole background.

```
.wrapper {
    background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/desktop.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 950px;
}
```

Comment: @RobertClarke your background only shows behind the div. The div is limited to the forms right now. Either add more padding or content, or change he height of the div

Comment: @RobertClarke what did you do? It’s good to accept an answer or write your own answer so future visitors can see how the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to set the height of the `<div class="wrapper">` to 100vh.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This set the height of the divider to 100% of the window view height. Before it was going to 100% of the height of the forms.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/desktop.jpg);
```

with

```
background:url(../images/backgrounds/desktop.jpg) no-repeat scroll;
```